# quit command does not work after running the selenium automatic downloading tasks

Tags: python, selenium, firefox

The "driver.quit()" does not work when I run the automatic downloading task in selenium, but if there is no download task in the browser, the quit command still works.

I would it be that quit the browser after completing the downloading in order to relaunch the browser and then run the loop of downloading batches of files.

I use the latest version of geckodriver v0.25.0 (mac-version) and Firefox <69.0.1>

---

### Here is my code:

```
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()

profile.set_preference('browser.download.folderList', 2)
profile.set_preference('browser.download.dir', os.getcwd())
profile.set_preference('browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting', False)
profile.set_preference('browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk', 'application/pdf')

profile.set_preference("plugin.disable_full_page_plugin_for_types", "application/pdf")
profile.set_preference("pdfjs.disabled", True)
profile.set_preference("browser.download.manager.closeWhenDone", True)

driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile)

driver.implicitly_wait(10)

driver.get("https://static.mozilla.com/foundation/documents/mf-irs-501c3-application-form-872-c.pdf")

driver.quit()
```

---

### I got error message like:

```
TimeoutException                          Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-80-c56ffa95cb91> in <module>
      1 driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile)
----> 2 
driver.get("https://static.mozilla.com/foundation/documents/mf-irs-501c3-application-form-872-c.pdf")
      3 driver.quit()

/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py in get(self, url)
    331         Loads a web page in the current browser session.
    332         """
--> 333         self.execute(Command.GET, {'url': url})
    334 
    335     @property

/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py in execute(self, driver_command, params)
    319         response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
    320         if response:
--> 321             self.error_handler.check_response(response)
    322             response['value'] = self._unwrap_value(
    323                 response.get('value', None))

/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py in check_response(self, response)
    240                 alert_text = value['alert'].get('text')
    241             raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace, alert_text)
--> 242         raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
    243 
    244     def _value_or_default(self, obj, key, default):

TimeoutException: Message: Timeout loading page after 300000ms
```

Answer (score 1):

I tested it with the requests library, which I think is a networking problem.Try another proxy?

```
import requests
url = "https://static.mozilla.com/foundation/documents/mf-irs-501c3-application-form-872-c.pdf"
r = requests.get(url)
with open('your.pdf','wb') as file:
    file.write(r.content)
```

so, I think the problem with selenium in your code is also a network problem

requests not change proxy
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fuP3t.png)

requests change my proxy(taiwan...)/or use my baidu server
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eVCZt.png)
almost download it